# How to Dynamically change drawable's id in setImageResource() Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-resources

My Question is how to change image id from drawable folder in setImageResource() in android.
My drawable folder contains icon0.png to icon9.png and i want to change these images in image view dynamically using this

```
 ImageView iV3;
iV3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
iV3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon + speed_Arr[2]);
```

speed_Arr[2] contains any value from 0 - 9.
But this didnt change images.
Plz help me out.
regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int getIdentifier(Context context, String name)
{
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Above code will return the resource id from name String.

Answer (score 0):

**int res = getResources().getIdentifier("< packageName:drawable/imageName >'", null, null);**
Use this res in your iV3.